# Error login with RDP and Active Directory

Tags: windows, windows-8, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

have a problem when I try to loggin from a PC - Windows 8 - (using RDP) to a Windows Server (2008r2) that has Active Directory running. I can't access the server. (I put my credentials right)

This is the message I receive.

> Logon failure: user account restriction. Possible reasons are blank
>   passwords not allowed, logon hour restrictions, or a policy
>   restriction has been enforced

The strange thing is that it only happens on a single PC, if I try it with other PCs it does not cause any problems and I can access it well using RDP.

I don't know if it's a problem with Active Directory or with RDP.

With the same users (and also with other users) I can connect in another machine. The problem simply occurs on a PC.

Comment: Are you the administrator of the server or a user?

Comment: administrator ... I tried it with 2 different administrators- @Travis

Comment: In AD Users and Computers check the **Account** tab > **Log On To** and **Logon Hours**. Otherwise on the machine with the issue, check this GP setting as per indicated here: https://superuser.com/questions/1018825/restrict-remote-desktop-access-to-specific-users-to-specific-servers-in-a-domain in the answer I wrote about which is the accepted solution.

Comment: Thank you for responding @PimpJuiceIT, **Log on** and **The login hours** are fine. (Screenshot [link] (https://imgur.com/s1SxgCl) [link] (https://imgur.com/if4cs84)).
I checked the GP configuration and the list of denied users was empty.