# Windows Server 2016, Active Directory, disable access to all servers except one for specific user

Tags: remote-desktop, active-directory, windows-server-2016

Specific scenario with active directory: Users logon to remote desktop via RDP and access through an RD gateway. There is one specific user that I do not want to grant access to any other server besides that specific "limited_access_server".

I've tried the "Log In to" under the user's 
`Preferences -> Account -> Log In To`

And found that wasn't what I needed, because the name is misleading and actually means FROM and TO, both are needed. But because this is a remote connection from possibly anywhere, I only have the TO part.. which is the "limited_access_server".

Is there no good way to limit a person to 1 server only?

Comment: [have you tried this superuser solution?](https://superuser.com/questions/1018825/restrict-remote-desktop-access-to-specific-users-to-specific-servers-in-a-domain)

Comment: Thanks, read it and doesn't seem to be the solution. That would block off all RDP peer to peer (local computers). Which is fine, but that would also stop RDP from a remote location into the 1 "limited_access_server".

Answer (score 0):

You could expel that account form domain **Remote Desktop Users** group and **Domain Users** group, and just manually add that user to local **Remote Desktop Users** on that server and if needed in local **Administrators** of that server.

[image]